# ASP.NET IIS user role authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis-8

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET MVC4 website.
And in that website i wan't users that are part of an certain role to be allowed to run the code.
I use the following code:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = GROUP)]
    public void Auth()
    {
        /* if user is in the domain and signed in
         * and a member of the above group 
         * they will come here */

        username = User.Identity.Name;

        //Do somthing
    }
```

And this works great, but when the user isn't part of the domain and/or group it wil prompt for username and password. Is it possible to skip the prompt and just redirect that user?

This website is setup in a IIS 8 with authentication set to windows authentication

Comment: r u using windows authentication?

Comment: Yes, in a IIS 8 with authentication set to windows authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I would create a Custom Authorization Attribute and implement HandleUnauthorizedRequest method to solve this problem.

```
public class CustomAutorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
      // do authorization logic
      // ...


      return (/* isAuthorized */);
   }


   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
      UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);


      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Error"));
   }
}
```

For more information read [How to: Create a Custom Authorization Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

Comment: this is the correct way of authorization as you wanted to tell the user that you don't have the permission.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 [Authorize(Roles = GROUP)]
  [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), View = "ApplicationError")]
    public void Auth()
    {
        /* if user is in the domain and signed in
         * and a member of the above group 
         * they will come here */

        username = User.Identity.Name;

        //Do somthing
    }
```

where you can sepcify view for unauthorized access user

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still prompts for username and password